# Verb contractions with thou

Tags: contractions, thou-thee-thy

I know there are a lot of commonly accepted contractions (verb + not): *aren't, haven't, isn't, don't, won't, shan't*, etc.

But do the contractions for *art not, hast not, dost not, wilt not, shalt not*, etc. exist?

Comment: "thou art" -> "thou'rt"  Your title does not specify using "not", but your body does.

Answer (score 1):

There are for hast not and dost not, *hastn't* and *dostn't*
At least if you google these, you will get mentions in some books

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here are some ones I could find.

Thou has thou'st for thou hast, and there's also th'art for thou art.

As for art not, there is no known contraction of the form *artn't, but there is "bisn't", a contraction of bist not, with bist being the West Country form of art.  Thou hadst and wouldst have the contraction thou'dst. Thou wilt and shalt take "thou'lt".  Besides that, I would expect shan't can be used in place of shalt not, though I would recomend using thou'lt not if you want to be clear.

There's also the joking contraction of th'all, meaning thou all.

Apart from that, I think "thou" might live on in the north of England, so someone needs to go there and do the field research to figure out how the contractions of "tha" are formed.

Upon looking into it a bit further, it seems there’s also “tha’ll” for “thou will”, and “tha’v” [sic] for “thou have”.  It seems “tha’v” is used “tha’v to” to mean “thou has to”, or “thou must”.

Comment: Can you cite some sources?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).